# Bing maps control wpf map tiles are being shuffled

Tags: c#, wpf, bing-maps

I am building a demo for a client using the [Bingmaps WPF Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh745791.aspx). I got a dev-license and used one of the [basic examples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh830433.aspx).

The program compiles and I am able to use the map the same way I'd do via a browser. The problem is that something is going wrong when rendering because the map data is shuffled and thus the map tiles do not overlap neatly as seen in the picture below.

[image: Wanna play a game?]

This does not seem to be a widespread problem as I found only [one similar question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/532c6c29-e162-4b44-8141-772a622aebfd/wpf-bing-maps-control-display-issue?forum=bingmapsservices&prof=required) asked on the Microsoft Support Forums, which unfortunately went (pretty much) unanswered. Any ideas?

I am using .NET Framework 4, Visual Studio 2013.

Answer (score 0):

It was a proxy/firewall issue at work. When I tried the demo at home it worked just fine.

Comment: I am having a similar issue. How did you determine the firewall was the problem?